call a function in ActionState with argument in Nextjs
I want to use ActioState hook for this remove button handler function:
    const RemoveButton = ({ task }: { task: Task }) => {
    const [state, handleRemoveTask, ispending] = useActionState(removeTask, {
        message: "",
    });
    return (
        <div>
        <button
            onClick={async () => await handleRemoveTask(task.id)}
            className="text-red-500 text-3xl hover:text-red-700 focus:outline-none"
            aria-label={`Delete task: ${task.text}`}
            // disabled={ispending ? true : false}
        >
            Remove
        </button>
        </div>
    );
    };

with the action:
export async function removeTask(taskId: number) {
  const res = await query("DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id = $1", [taskId]);
  if (res.rowCount === 0) {
    return {
      message: "failed to remove you task please refresh or try again later",
    };
  }
  revalidatePath("/");
  return { message:'' };
}

but I don't see how I can call it with argument like :
onClick={async () => await handleRemoveTask(task.id)}

calling remove task directly works fine:
 onClick={async () => await removeTask(task.id)}


Use best pratices in netxjs official website:
    const [state, action, ispending] = useActionState(removeTask, {
        message: "",
    });
    return (
        <form action={action} >
        <input hidden type="text" name="id" defaultValue={id}/>
        <button
            type="submit"
            className="text-red-500 text-3xl hover:text-red-700 focus:outline-none"
            aria-label={`Delete task: ${task.text}`}
            // disabled={ispending ? true : false}
        >
            Remove
        </button>
        </div>
    );
    };

get id in formData in action function:
export async function removeTask(_prevState:any,formData:FormData) {
  const taskId=formdate.get("id");
  const res = await query("DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id = $1", taskId);
  if (res.rowCount === 0) {
    return {
      message: "failed to remove you task please refresh or try again later",
    };
  }
  revalidatePath("/");
  return { message:'' };
}


Thank you but i already tried that, it doesn't work

@tahamaatof 100% works, maybe forget set name on id input.

my bad, retried it and it worked, i just forgot to save, but since the documentation assert that we can use onClick, i really wanted to try and see how we could manage it.
